# Unable to get Wireless working during Arch Linux install

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, chroot

I'm following the Arch Linux install guide here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide

I'm installing from a live disc. I've just used pacstrap to install the base system. I then used chroot to configure the system (time zones, language, etc.)

My wireless has been working fine up to this point but only on the live disc and through `wifi-menu`. From my understanding I now need to get Wi-Fi working on the actual system.

I'm choosing to do this manually with `netctl`. I enter the netctl directory and notice that there is a profile already created there for me. I'm guessing this is because wifi-menu automatically created it for me. So I run:

```
netctl enable wlp2s0-linksys
```

I receive the error message `running in chroot, ignoring request`

A ping to Google shows that I am still not connected. How can I set this netctl profile to be used on boot when I'm running off of the hdd from the actual installation and not the disc?

Comment: What @strugee said. Notice this warning on the page you linked to: "Warning: This must be done *after* your reboot when you are no longer chrooted. The process spawned by this command will conflict with the one you have running outside of the chroot. Alternatively, you could just configure a network profile manually using the following templates so that you do not have to worry about using wifi-menu at all." Just reboot into your new system and configure it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. This behavior is expected, so you'll need to set up your wifi a second time after rebooting into the hard drive.

Note that you'll probably have to run `wifi-menu` again, as the network configuration won't have been copied to the chroot.

Comment: Ok. But I still have to install the bootloader through pacman. Will this work offline? After that, should I just go ahead and unmount,reboot without cd, and then proceed to get the wireless working?

Comment: @user49728 the internet connection will persist into the chroot. At least it _should_.