# How to connect to internet when installing Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, internet

I am new to arch-linux, I have only used Ubuntu in the past. I am trying to install arch-linux on my computer, and it boots up to the terminal interface successfully, but I am unable to connect to the internet, so I can't install any packages via `pacman`, which I need to do since I need to install the desktop-environment, and other packages. I looked at the [official installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide#Configure_the_system) and I tried `ip link` to connect to it. It game me an error, and I tried `ip-link(8)` to see if it was listed, but it told me the command was not found. I'm not sure what to do now. Can someone help me out?

Comment: What is your internet connection type: wifi, ethernet, something other? `ip-link(8)` is not a single command but command `ip` with parameter `link`, you said you already run it. What is it's output?

Comment: `ip-link(8)` refers to a man page, not a command. Try `man 8 ip-link` to see it. You said `ip link` gave an error, but you didn't say what error. `ip link` shows network interfaces; it does not connect anything. How do you need to connect? Via ethernet? Via wifi? Normally, an ethernet connection should just work, but for wifi, you'd [connect using `iwctl`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Iwd#iwctl) on the live environment.

Comment: We can't help you fix an error if we don't know what it is. So please [edit] your question and show us the exact error you are receiving.

Comment: Relating (duplicate?) - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97323/unable-to-get-wireless-working-during-arch-linux-install and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615054/arch-linux-install-wlan0-is-up-but-not-connecting-to-wi-fi

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by using ethernet, instead of attempting to connect to a WiFi network. After connecting my ethernet cable, I could get online and install packages. Thank you to @frabjous for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

`iwctl` command.

To use it list devices, and get the first item (e.g `wlan0`). Then run this command:

```
station wlan0 connect *router ssid here*
```